# Javafx collision detection with sprites having transparent backgorund

Tags: javafx, collision, detection

I am making a game in javafx. The image of the sprite is used in ImageView. For collision detection, I can use the getBoundsInParent() but it checks with the rectangle part. I want the collision detection to work in a way that the transaprent background is ignored. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Most programs, javafx included, work under the assumption that images are rectangular, with a given width and height, regardless of which parts of the image are transparent. The bounds of the image, therefore, are obviously going to be the rectangle. If you wanted some way to create a Shape based off of which pixels of an image are transparent and which aren't, that's going to be a lot more difficult than just using getBoundsInParent(). You're going to need to do some research and code writing yourself, and then maybe come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: You should use the bounds to do a first, quick, check if there might be a collision because the two rectangles overlap. If so the next step might be to check if two polygon shapes describing the opaque parts have an overlap, and after that you could compare at pixel level.

Comment: One thing I can do is change the bounds value to be a little bit smaller than the original bounds of my sprite. Can you tell me what the six double variables in the intersects method parameters stand for?